# How do I YAML dump without the class information?

Tags: ruby, yaml, middleman

I am dumping an array of Test class objects, and my YAML is showing this:

```
---
- !ruby/object:Test
  id: rec1NIfdJz
- !ruby/object:Test
  id: rec1R9TtHF
```

The problem arises when I use Middleman and then it throws an error for YAML parsing.

```sh
YAML Exception parsing ... undefined class/module Test
```

Comment: What is `Test`? How does it look like? How do you dump to YAML? How does this play together with middleman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reduce it to some kind of plain Ruby structure like a Hash first, like:

```
YAML.dump(object.to_h)
```

If you have, or could implement a simple `.to_h` method.

YAML, like Marshal, will try and preserve the Ruby class represented by that object. Neutral forms like JSON don't, so that could be an alternative.